# Operation overloading in composite design pattern in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, composite

Suppose I have this code all set up:

```
class Function
{
public:
    virtual double eval(double x) const =0;
};

class Polynomial : public Function
{
private:
    std::vector<double> coefficients;
public:
    // ...
};

class CompositeFunction : public Function
{
private:
    char operation;
    Function* left;
    Function* right;
public:
    // ...  
};

CompositeFunction operator+(Function& f, Function& g) {
    return CompositeFunction('+',&f,&g);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to do the following thing:

```
CompositeFunction f = Polynomial({1,2}) + Polynomial({3,2});
printf("%lf\n",f.eval(1));
```

I don't get any compilation errors but when I try to eval f, Valgrind tells me I'm acessing bad data. I always get the correct answer but this is bugging me off.
I have tried to stop using stack-allocated arguments but I can't overload any pointer operation.
Is there any pointer-less way or friendly for the users of these classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because f has references to two temporary objects.

Expand it out to make it more obvious:

```
CompositeFunction f = operator+( Polynomial({1,2}), Polynomial({3,2}) );
```

f now holds references to the temporaries created by Polynomial({1,2}) and Polynomial({3,2}).

You might want to consider using `std::function<double(double)>` objects and lambdas, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

typedef std::function<double(double)> Function;

Function polynomial(std::vector<double> const &coefficients) {
    return [coefficients](double x) {
        return x * coefficients[0]; // dummy evaluation
    };
}

Function add(Function f1, Function f2) {
    return [f1, f2](double x) { return f1(x) + f2(x); };
}

int main() {
    Function f = add(polynomial({3,4}), polynomial({1,2}));
    std::cout << f(3.3) << std::endl;
}
```

Here it is with std::shared_ptr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Function
{
public:
    virtual double eval(double x) const = 0;
    virtual double derivative(double x) const = 0;
    virtual ~Function() {}
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<Function> FunctionPtr;

class Polynomial : public Function
{
private:
    std::vector<double> coefficients;
public:
    // ...
    Polynomial(std::vector<double> c) : coefficients(c) {}
};

class CompositeFunction : public Function
{
private:
    char operation;
    FunctionPtr left;
    FunctionPtr right;
public:
    // ...
    CompositeFunction(FunctionPtr l, FunctionPtr r) : operation('+'), left(l), right(r) {}
};

FunctionPtr operator+(FunctionPtr f, FunctionPtr g) {
    return std::make_shared<CompositeFunction>(f, g);
}

int main() {
    auto p1 = std::make_shared<Polynomial>(std::vector<double>{1.0, 2.0});
    auto p2 = std::make_shared<Polynomial>(std::vector<double>{3.0, 4.0});
    auto f = std::make_shared<CompositeFunction>(p1, p2);
    auto f2 = p1 + p2;
    std::cout << f2->eval(3.3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f2->derivative(3.3) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have noticed this. Tried to copy them but I can't access their copy constructors because they are now Functions.  
Maybe adding a copy function to the interface is a good idea?

Comment: If you used std::function objects, they can be passed by value.

Comment: I didn't knew about `std::function`, it looks very cool. However, evaluating these functions are not my only concern, to evaluate their derivatives are also very important and this can be easily done by the tree structure and the evaluation of the derivatives of "basic" functions.  
That's the main reason of my decision to "reinvent the wheel"

Comment: No matter what, you need to stop passing the functors around by reference because you can't copy them.  I'd probably switch to passing std::shared_ptr instead.  That way you can safely keep the leaves in your expression tree, without worrying about slicing.

Comment: I see, what should be the signature of `operator+`? Or should I stop trying to use overloaded operators?